# My iphone tab bar controller is appearing small

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitabbarcontroller

I have login screen when the app is launched. And am able to switch between the views in my next view (tab bar controller). But my tab bar controller is appearing small on the bottom. I have created my app using view based application. Can anyone help me out with the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it best to structure apps with login screens so that the login screen is modally presented (immediately upon app start) on top of the "main" screen (the tab bar controller in your case), and then dismiss the model login screen when login is finished, which reveals the main app screen underneath

Comment: there is no overlapping of my views. i have tried all the possibilities